# Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected

Tags: youtube-api

I am facing this error my code is

```
<a href='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
                state=%2Fprofile&amp;
                client_id=524265562778.apps.googleusercontent.com&
                redirect_uri=https://localhost/oauth2callback.html&
                scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&
                response_type=code&amp'>Login</a>
```

when i click on allow access the above error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the url values should be urlencode.

Comment: I resolved it. because i was working on http and redirect uri was https it was not supporting secure http